# Problem with DataSource creation on Google Fit REST API (Oxygen Saturation)

Tags: api, rest, google-fit

[google-fit] Hi! i'd like to know how to create a Oxygen Saturation Data Source. I've already tried many combinations, without success, always receiving "Data type does not match well-known data type with the same name" from API. My only guess is that there is something wrong with my current ***field*** construction:

```
{
"dataStreamId": "derived:com.google.oxygen_saturation:xxxxxxxxxxx",
"name": "myapp-oxygen_saturation-datasource-derived",
"type": "derived",
"dataType": {
    "name": "com.google.oxygen_saturation",
    "field": [
        {
            "name": "oxygen_saturation",
            "format": "floatPoint"
        },
        {
            "name": "supplemental_oxygen_flow_rate",
            "format": "floatPoint"
        }
    ]
},
"application": {
    "name": "myapp-derived"
}
```

}

but there seems to be no real example on how to doing it using the REST Api. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Should `dataType` be wrapped in `[ {` `} ]` as well?

Comment: Remove the `"field"` key and value. Fit will then fill in the correct data types for you.

Answer (score 0):

As described [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/fit/datatypes/restricted#oxygen_saturation), the `com.google.oxygen_saturation` data type has 5 fields.

You're only supplying 2, so that's mismatched with what Fit is expecting. (The names, types and optionality also have to match).

Instead of trying to supply the field definitions yourself, just remove the `"field"` key and value. Fit will then fill in the correct fields for you, and return them in the response.